# Is there a way to display: none; all but one element using if statement?

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, hide, hidden

Trying to hide all but one product card so that the one displayed product card can be turned into a carousel to display the hidden product cards when carousel buttons are clicked.

Product cards will only be hidden when screen size is less that 600px (see media queries)

```
Javascript

let productIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("product-card")[0];
let productCard = document.getElementsByClassName("product-card");


if (productCard !== productIndex) {
productCard.style.display = "none";
}
```

The above code block will not hide the product cards but

```
if (productCard !== productIndex) {
productIndex.style.display = "none";
}
```

will hide the first the product.

[jsfiddle available here](https://jsfiddle.net/araSaraP/boct58uz/81/)

Comment: So you're comparing the productIndex card with a collection of cards. That's always a mismatch. You need to loop over the collection of cards comparing each one in turn with the productIndex card.

Comment: like so ` productIndex !== productCard` ? In doing so, the same thing occurs, the product cards are still displayed

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle, I see 5 product cards. If you just want to hide all but the first one when the screen width is less than 600px, then something like this would work:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

function resize() {
  let productCards = document.getElementsByClassName("product-card");
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    for (var i = 1; i < productCards.length; i++) {
      productCards[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i < productCards.length; i++) {
      productCards[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
  }
}
```

Grab the collection of cards, loop through them starting from the second element, and apply the style depending on the screen width. The event listener makes it responsive.

**Edit**: There's an even easier approach; instead of using javascript, you can put this inside of your media(max-width: 600px) block:

```
.product-card:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Would the (window.innerWidth < 600) condition still be needed if the 600px break is already in the media query?

Comment: It's because we can't run javascript from CSS (as far as I know), so I put the check there. NOTE: Check out my edit.

Comment: Added the code and disabled the media query as having both active caused a loading of both elements creating a visual issue.